# Problem with blade values not passing fast enough to the css?

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-blade, tailwind-css

I am having a weird issue and I believe it is because the blade values are not passing fast enough to the page vs the actual CSS. I have a grid in tailwind like this within a blade template:

```
<div class="mt-4 md:m-0 grid sm:grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-{{$count}} lg:grid-cols-{{$count}} xl:grid-cols-{{$count}} gap-2 content-evenly">
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
</div>
```

When I read the dom after the dom is loaded, I am getting the correct values as:

```
<div class="mt-4 md:m-0 grid sm:grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-5 lg:grid-cols-5 xl:grid-cols-5 gap-2 content-evenly">
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
</div>
```

But in my front end only the grid sm:grid-cols-1 works. I can only see 1 column.

Now here is the weird thing, if I replace by hand all the {{$count}} to "5", only then I will get the correct grid count.

From what I understand, the CSS loads before the PHP code and can only read the first grid sm:grid-cols-1

tailwind.config.js

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './resources/**/*.blade.php',
    './resources/**/*.js',
    './resources/**/*.vue',
    './node_modules/flowbite/**/*.js'
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
        fontFamily: {
            montserrat: ['Montserrat'],
            sans: ['Inter var', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
        },
        screens: {
            sm: '640px',
            md: '768px',
            lg: '1024px',
            xl: '1280px',
            '2xl': '1536px',
        },
        colors: {
            transparent: 'transparent',
            current: 'currentColor',
            'yellow': '#FFDD03',
            'yellow-form': '#FFDD0366',
            "red": {
                "50": "#fe3232",
                "100": "#f42828",
                "200": "#ea1e1e",
                "300": "#e01414",
                "400": "#d60a0a",
                "500": "#cc0000",
                "600": "#c20000",
                "700": "#b80000",
                "800": "#ae0000",
                "900": "#a40000"
            },
            "teal": {
                "50": "#72e2f1",
                "100": "#68d8e7",
                "200": "#5ecedd",
                "300": "#54c4d3",
                "400": "#4abac9",
                "500": "#40b0bf",
                "600": "#36a6b5",
                "700": "#2c9cab",
                "800": "#2292a1",
                "900": "#188897"
            },
            "green": {
                "50": "#ffffbd",
                "100": "#f5ffb3",
                "200": "#ebffa9",
                "300": "#e1ff9f",
                "400": "#d7f595",
                "500": "#cdeb8b",
                "600": "#c3e181",
                "700": "#b9d777",
                "800": "#afcd6d",
                "900": "#a5c363"
            },
            "blue": {
                "50": "#72c8ff",
                "100": "#68beff",
                "200": "#5eb4ff",
                "300": "#54aaff",
                "400": "#4aa0f8",
                "500": "#4096ee",
                "600": "#368ce4",
                "700": "#2c82da",
                "800": "#2278d0",
                "900": "#186ec6"
            },
            "orange": {
                "50": "#ffa632",
                "100": "#ff9c28",
                "200": "#ff921e",
                "300": "#ff8814",
                "400": "#ff7e0a",
                "500": "#ff7400",
                "600": "#f56a00",
                "700": "#eb6000",
                "800": "#e15600",
                "900": "#d74c00"
            },
            "black": {
                "50": "#565555",
                "100": "#4c4b4b",
                "200": "#424141",
                "300": "#383737",
                "400": "#2e2d2d",
                "500": "#242323",
                "600": "#1a1919",
                "700": "#100f0f",
                "800": "#060505",
                "900": "#000000"
            }
        },
        rotate: {
            '5': '5deg',
        },
        keyframes: {
            'fade-in': {
                '0%': {
                    opacity: '0',
                },
                '100%': {
                    opacity: '1',
                },
            },
            'fade-out': {
                '100%': {
                    opacity: '1',
                },
                '0%': {
                    opacity: '0',
                },
            },
            'roll-in-blurred-right': {
                "0%": {
                    transform: "translateX(1000px) rotate(720deg)",
                    filter: "blur(50px)",
                    opacity: "0"
                },
                to: {
                    transform: "translateX(0) rotate(0deg)",
                    filter: "blur(0)",
                    opacity: "1"
                }
            }
        },
        animation: {
            'fade-in': 'fade-in 0.5s',
            'slow-fade-in': 'fade-in 1s',
            'fade-out': 'fade-out 0.5s',
            'slow-fade-out': 'fade-out 1s',
            'roll-in-blurred-right': 'roll-in-blurred-right 0.65s cubic-bezier(0.230, 1.000, 0.320, 1.000)   both'
        },
        },
  },
    variants: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [
        require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
        require('@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio'),
        require("daisyui"),
        require('flowbite/plugin')
    ],
}
```

Any idea how to go around this please?

Thank you

Comment: Blade files are compiled _before_ being sent to your device, so the HTML should already contain the "5" when it arrives there. View caching issue maybe? Try `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: It could also be that you compress/minify your TailwindCSS (maybe by default). And 'md:grid-cols-' doesn't exists as a class. If that's the case you can have an if-else within your blade file and add the 'md:grid-cols-5' instead of 'md:grid-cols-{{ count }}'.

Comment: @Tjardo that should be the correct answer as it is typical [dynamic](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names) classes issue

Comment: If you check the thread again, I added my tailwind config, the screens are all there..

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to use [Dynamic Class Names](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names) which is not recommended.

However, you can get around this by [Safetlisting classes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes).

For example, you could add the following to `tailwind.config.js`.

This will compile all the defined classes regardless of whether they are used in your blade templates such as `md:grid-cols-5`, `grid-cols-3`, etc.

```js
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  safelist: [
    {
      // Option A - Add as needed
      pattern: /grid-cols-(1|2|3|4|5)/,
      // Option B - Overkill, but easier to maintain
      // * is a wildcard, and will take longer to compile
      pattern: /grid-cols-*/,
      variants: ['sm', 'md', 'lg', 'xl'], // for xx: prefixes
    },
  ],
  // ...
}
```